# Spring batch with spring data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-batch

Is there a way to integrate spring batch with spring data? I see **RepositoryItemReader** and **RepositoryItemWriter** in spring documentation.

Comment: That's the way to do it.  Was there something else you were looking for?

Comment: well i'm doing that in a different way i'm injecting the service into the job configuration and invoke the method that's available on the JpaRepository, like this example

        @ Bean
 @ StepScope
 public ItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter2() {
  return items -> {
   for (Customer item : items) {
    
    customerService.save(item);
   }
  };
 }

Comment: Why would you do that when we have the `RepositoryItemWriter` for you?

Comment: I have discovered it this day by hazard it will be better to use it,and I would like to thank you for all the course that you have made on O'Reilly it really helped me a lot.

Comment: @MichaelMinella could you answer my other question please thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008684/local-partionnig-in-spring-batch

Answer (score 3):

You are totally right. Spring batch can be easily be integrated with spring data. Here example of item reader:

```
    @Bean(name = "lotteryInfoReader")
    @StepScope
    public RepositoryItemReader<LotteryInfo> reader() {
        RepositoryItemReader<LotteryInfo> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        reader.setRepository(lotteryInfoRepository);
        reader.setMethodName("findAll");
        reader.setSort(Collections.singletonMap("name", Sort.Direction.ASC));
        return reader;
    }
```

Here is another example with using hibernate without spring data :

```
    @Bean(name = "drawsWriter")
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<? super List<Draw>> writer() {
        return items -> items.stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .forEach(entityManager::merge);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well i'm doing that in a different way i'm injecting the service into the job configuration and invoke the method that's available on the JpaRepository, like this example

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter2() {
        return items -> {
            for (Customer item : items) {

                customerService.save(item);
            }
        };
    }
```