# Local Partitioning in Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, partitioning

I'm actually using local partitioning to export customer table that has 100K rows to multiple XML files ( as i can't export data to one file because `StaxEventItemWriter<T>` isn't Thread-safe) but i don't get better results with multiple Threads even when increasing `gridSize` to 10. I think the problem in the StaxEventItemWriter because i have some code errors like :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.flush(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:397) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLEventWriterImpl.flush(XMLEventWriterImpl.java:212) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.close(StaxEventItemWriter.java:674) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:354) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:277) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.run(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:236) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext.close(StepContext.java:213) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepSynchronizationManager$1.close(StepSynchronizationManager.java:53) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepSynchronizationManager$1.close(StepSynchronizationManager.java:36) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.SynchronizationManagerSupport.release(SynchronizationManagerSupport.java:190) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepSynchronizationManager.release(StepSynchronizationManager.java:112) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.doExecutionRelease(AbstractStep.java:290) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:278) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
```

**Reader**

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> pagingItemReader(
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['minValue']}")Long minValue,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['maxValue']}")Long maxValue) {
        System.out.println("reading " + minValue + " to " + maxValue);
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();

        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setFetchSize(10000);
        reader.setRowMapper(new CustomerRowMapper());

        MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        queryProvider.setSelectClause("id, firstName, lastName, birthdate");
        queryProvider.setFromClause("from customer");
        queryProvider.setWhereClause("where id >= " + minValue + " and id <= " + maxValue);

        Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>(1);

        sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);

        queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);

        return reader;
    }
```

**Writer**

```
 @Bean
    @StepScope
    public StaxEventItemWriter<Customer> bookItemWriter(
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['ressource']}")Object ressource
        ) {

        XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();

        StaxEventItemWriter<Customer> itemWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();

        itemWriter.setRootTagName("customers");
        itemWriter.setMarshaller(marshaller());




        File file = new File("C\\resources\\data\\"+ressource+".xml");

        String customerOutputPath=file.getAbsolutePath();

        itemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(customerOutputPath));



        return itemWriter;
    }
```

**Partitionner**

```
@Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        int min = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MIN(" + column + ") from " + table, Integer.class);
        int max = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MAX(" + column + ") from " + table, Integer.class);
        int targetSize = (max - min) / gridSize + 1;

        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
        int number = 0;
        int start = min;
        int end = start + targetSize - 1;

        while (start <= max) {
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
            result.put("partition" + number, value);


            if (end >= max) {
                end = max;
            }
            value.putInt("minValue", start);
            value.putInt("maxValue", end);

            String partition = "partition" + number;

            value.putString("ressource",partition);

            start += targetSize;
            end += targetSize;
            number++;
        }

        return result;
    }}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What profiling have you done?

Comment: Sorry ? I want to export the customer table data to XML files because i'm going to use the MultiResourcePartitioner when importing those files to database, my main objective is to gain time as much as possible

Comment: As I said, what profiling have you done to determine what the bottle neck is?

Comment: I haven't done any profiling i'm using only Partitioning

Comment: You need to profile your app to find out what the bottle neck is.